# Why iphone 4 & ipad width look similar?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I have added a view in my app. I want the view to look equal on all the devices. So I have applied below constraints. The width of iPhone 4 & iPad looks similar so I want to know it is happening. Below are my constraints.

[image]

In case of iPhone 5,6,6+ the width is looks similar

Constraints are as follows

[image]

Comment: try trail and lead constraint instead of assign view to centre and use aspect ratio with parent view constraint only....It will help

Comment: I am asking why iPhone 4 & iPad looks similar?